# MongoDb: Delete specific collections

Tags: mongodb, collections

I am trying to delete all collections in a MongoDB, where the maximum document date in these collections is older than 1 year.
Everything I tried hasn't worked yet, so I'm hoping that you can help me :)
Thanks very much!

Comment: Maximum date of the variable "date". So in MySQL it would be like "...having max(date) < current_date-365"

Comment: sorry, still don't understand. do you want to delete all the collections where all the documents in these collections are older than 1 year? where at least 1 document is older than 1 year?  what is the query you don't succeed to do?

Comment: Correct! I Would like to delete all the collections where all the documents in these collections are older than 1 year! :)

Comment: In all the collections you have a 'date' field in the schema?

Comment: Yes, that's correct!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you mean you have a 'date' field in all of your collections schemas.

You can do something like this, but be aware that it will drop also all the collections that doesn't have a 'date' field.

```js
db.getCollectionNames().forEach(function (collection) {

 var lastYear = new Date();
 lastYear.setFullYear(lastYear.getFullYear() - 1);
 
 var collectionCount = db[collection].count({date: {$gt: lastYear}});
 
 if (0 === collectionCount) {
  db[collection].drop();
 }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You are telling you want to delete the collection where all documents are older than a year 
so You Intialise a Iterator 
Then use count aggregation, if  the count value is more than one then use "drop" to drop the collection :)